# Read bytes from socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a Socket in Java (`java.net.ServerSocket`). I read from it using `InputStream`.

I would like to read several bytes from socket, when they are available. So I use `InputStream.read(bytes, 0, num)`.

It works fine when I test it locally (over 127.0.0.1). But when I put it on internet and connect to it, it reads only 2916 bytes. How can I read exactly "num" bytes and don't continue, unitl I receive them?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Are you checking the return value of the `InputStream.read()`?

Comment: Undoubtedly your code is wrong. Post it here, by editing it into your reply.

Comment: Posting how you think your code works is pointless, as it doesn't do what you think it does. Post the *actual* code. What for example does 'when they are available' mean? What does the infinite loop look like?

Comment: I am sorry, I am so stupid. I just googled it and solved it. I used DataInputStream.readFully(bytes).

Really don't know why there is the third argument in InputStream.read(bytes, offset, length), when it reads only 2916 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like something to do with the way your network is set up.  Something else could be sending data to it.  Have you tried using a different port?

If that doesn't work, try disabling your network connection / disconnecting from your network to see if its something from outside which is actually causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, I changed port number for 5 times. Really don't know whats going on.

Comment: Try my second suggestion... might narrow down whether my post is even relevant.

Comment: So, it reads well first 4 bytes, but it has problems when I send bytes after that. It is OK when I don't send anything, but it reads wrong data when I send them to server. Seems like it mixes new bytes with bytes from previous message. I asked my teacher to update the version of Java.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You will need to take Jon Skeet's advice and give us some more info.

Comment: @IvanKuckir This is certainly not dependent on the version of Java.

Comment: Hello, I slightly edited the question. Sorry for that. Should I delete this question and start a new one?

Answer (score 2):

That is the way how readings of sockets usually works. When using slower 'network' than loopback, all data is not transferred immediately.

`read(bytes, 0, num)` will return when there is data available. There may be one or more bytes, even more than `num` bytes available. `num` only limits how much data is moved to `bytes` array.

So if you want to receive excatly `num` bytes, then you must call `read` again. Of cource with smaller `len` and bigger `off` parameters.

Example:

```
    int offset = 0;
    int wanted = buffer.length;

    while( wanted > 0 )
    {
        final int len = istream.read( buffer, offset, wanted );     
        if( len == -1 )
        {
            throw new java.io.EOFException( "Connection closed gracefully by peer" );
        }
        wanted -= len;
        offset += len;
    }
```